# How to determine the new domain and range given the old domain and range?

Tags: functions

"A function f(x) has domain $\{x \in \mathbb{R}\;|\;x \ge -4\}$ and range $\{y \in \mathbb{R}\;|\;y \lt -1\}$ Determine the domain and range of each function without graphing."

I was given the $2$ functions $y=f(-x)$ and $y=-2f(-x+5) + 1$.
For the first function, I understand why the the domain is $x \lt 4$ (everything is flipped because of $-1$), but I don't understand why it doesn't say that $x \le 4$.

For the second function, I don't understand why the range doesn't say $y$ $\gt 3$ . I also don't understand why the domain isn't $x \le -1$. Hopefully this post made sense.

Comment: Please check the first sentence in the last paragraph: "is less is greater than $1$" does not make sense.  Also, please read this [tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.  Using the proper mathematical symbolism would make your post easier to read.

Comment: I don't understand how the LaTeX works. I typed y \ge 3 but it didn't work.

Comment: See [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). You need to enclose it in `$` symbols, like `$y \ge 3$`.

Answer (score 2):

For the second function, let $g(x) = -2 f(-x+5) + 1$.

The argument passed to $f$ is $-x + 5$, and it must be in the domain of $f$, so:

$$-x + 5 \ge -4 \quad \iff \quad x \le 9$$

The range of values for $g(x)$ follows from:

$$f(-x + 5) \lt -1$$
$$-2 f(-x + 5) \gt 2$$
$$g(x) = -2 f(-x + 5) + 1 \gt 3$$

From the above, the domain of $g$ is $\{x \in \mathbb{R}\;|\; x \le 9\}$ and its range is $\{y \in \mathbb{R}\;|\; y \gt 3\}$.

The first function can be worked out the same way, and it's obviously simpler.

Comment: $\{x \in \mathbb{R}\;|\;x \lt -1\}$ and $\{y \in \mathbb{R}\;|\;y \lt 3\}$ was the textbook's answer. Would you say the textbook's answer is incorrect?

Comment: @Hamze That's either wrong, or maybe refers to a problem other than the one you posted. Simply by inspection it's easy to see that $f$ is always negative, so $-2 f(-x+5)$ is always positive, therefore the range of $y = -2 f(-x+5) + 1$ can *not* include any negative numbers.

Comment: I don't understand, how do you know f is always negative?

Comment: The domain is $x \ge -4$ and the range is $y \lt -1$ so $f(x) < -1 \lt 0$ for $\forall x \ge -4$.

Comment: Ok, I got how you found the range, but I don't understand how you got the domain. $-1x$ suggests horizontal compression, so  -4/-1= 4. I was taught to do the opposite of "x+h" so instead of adding 5 to x I'd subtract 5. Which gives me $x \le -1$ unless I'm reading it wrong and it actually means -(x-5) which would be interpreted differently.

Comment: From the answer: "*The argument passed to $f$ is $−x+5$, and it must be in the domain of $f$*". Stated another way, $f( \cdot )$ is defined for $\cdot \ge -4$. Replace the $\cdot$ with $-x+5$ and the inequality follows as written.

Comment: That actually makes sense. I believe you, it's just that I don't understand why the textbook would involve a question that requires solving inequalities when we haven't even covered inequalities in one way or another(or have we?). I don't remember solving inequalities in the lower grade levels either(right now it's grade 11 Functions).